# Some HTML for values of Hash keys

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am building a panel with a partial, but I'd like to customise the inside of the panel with some html. Is there any way to write some HTML for a hash value?

I have a custom partial *_panel_builder.html.erb* that I takes as argument `pclass`, `heading`, `body`, etc., that I would like to use like this :

*(The below syntax is bad, but I don't really understand how I could do something nice..)*

```
<% @etudes.each_with_index do |etude, i| %>
<%= render 'shared/panel_builder', 
    pclass: panel_color_rotation(i),
    heading: etude.name,
    # For the body param, I'd like to be able to use some HTML with occasional <%=...%> for variables, like :
    body: (%>
        <p><%=etude.description %></p>
        <ul>
        <%etude.competences.each do |comp| %>
            <li><strong><%= competence.name %></strong> : <%=competence.level %>
                <br><small><%=competence.why %></small>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    <%).html_safe,
    collapsable: true %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT : An idea of what my *_panel_builder* partial looks like :

```
<% 
collapsable ||= false
pclass ||= "default"
footer ||= false
%>


<div class="panel  panel-<%= pclass %> <%= if collapsable then "panel-collapsable " end %>">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <%= heading %> 
        <% if collapsable %> 
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span> 
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body <%= if collapsable then "collapse" end %>">
        <%= body %>
    </div>

    <% if footer %>
    <div class="panel-footer <%= if collapsable then "collapse" end %>">
        <%= footer %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this be a helper that takes a block? Specifying a body like this smells all kinds of wrong.

Comment: Problem is that in my case, I use a partial that uses 3 very abstract locals (`heading`, `body`, `footer`), and I'd like to be able to have some HTML (not written as a Ruby string) for the 3 of them...

Comment: @Dave Were you referring to the `capture` helper ? I just discovered this on the ruby doc website, seems to be what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was actually looking for the `capture` helper :

```
<% @etudes.each_with_index do |etude, i| %>
<%= render 'shared/panel_builder', 
    pclass: panel_color_rotation(i),
    heading: etude.name,
    body: capture do %>
        <p><%=etude.description %></p>
        <ul>
        <%etude.competences.each do |comp| %>
            <li><strong><%= competence.name %></strong> : <%=competence.level %>
                <br><small><%=competence.why %></small>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>,
    collapsible: true %>
<% end %>
```

Note : in some cases, I also want to pass a complex HTML block as the header of footer, so I can't just have a helper that takes a block.

Note2 : My panel is a HTML template made for generic data. I cannot pass it a Ruby object